Can't connect to ArcGIS Enterprise REST service on QGIS 3.28/3.34
I have a connection setup similar to this one:
This is in QGIS / Windows:
This connection works fine in QGIS 3.18.3. In any higher versions there is an error (Connection failed:Network error). The only way around I can see is that, install older version (3.18.3) make the connection to ArcGIS Server REST services, then install the higher version (3.34.9), and that connection is still honored (even after removing the older version from the computer). However this is not a practical solution, as the company IT policy do not allow to install older versions of the software. Any idea why this is so, or anyone observed similar issues with newer version of QGIS?
